# How to Display the Map<String,Map<String,List<SObject>>> Map in VF Page Block table

Tags: visualforce

I am trying to show...

```
Map<String,Map<String,List<SObject>>> mapRecords = new Map<String,Map<String,List<SObject>>>()
```

... in VF `<apex:pageBlockTable>` but I could not get it to work as required in using the above format in my VF page.

Can anyone please suggest how to approach this and implement it in a VF page?

Comment: it is Map<string,Map<string,list<sobject>>> mapRecords = new Map<string,Map<string,list<sobject>>>()

Comment: Hi Vijay, can you share what you've tried so far?

Comment: possible solution : http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/27523/using-pageblocktable-inside-other-pageblocktable

Comment: Can you **[edit your question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/142240/edit)** to include the portions of your controller or extension that build this map, as well as the getter method for this map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's going to roughly look like this:

```
<apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:repeat value="{!mapRecords}" var="key1">
        <apex:repeat value="{!mapRecords[key1]}" var="key2">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!mapRecords[key1][key2]}" var="record">
                <apex:column value="{!record.field}" />
            </apex:paeBlockTable>
        </apex:repeat>
   </apex:repeat>
```

Keep in mind that this will be *very* expensive in terms of view state size, so you must keep the data reasonably small.

You can swap around the tags pretty much any way you want, just remember that you need a total of three iterators to get to the records.

Comment: question on your comment about view state - If you use transient property on the map is it still expensive on the view state? I have switched to using apex class object instead of maps where I would have nested several maps but am curios if the use of the OP pattern is expensive by itself or only when not using transient.

Comment: @Eric The problem with nested repeats is that they explode the "internal state" part of view state. It's pretty easy to build a page that has 0 bytes of state and yet blows past the governor limit because of a few nested iterators.

Comment: Thanks, thats what I was wondering....I may be running into this exact issue with area/region/territory sales summaries on a VF Page broken down in tree form......Time to break out the development mode to inspect view state...